# How to subtract 2 values from 2 different columns of the same table with different WHERE conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to subtract 2 summed values from 2 different columns of the same table and then insert the single value into another table BUT the summed values are retrieved with different where conditions and I can't seem to find a solution!

First qry:

```
SELECT SUM(ticketTotalAmount)
 FROM tickets
WHERE ticketDate > dateadd(hh,-1,getdate()) 
    AND ticketDate < GETDATE() AND ticketState IN ('STAND BY' , 'WIN' , 'LOSE')
```

Second qry:

```
select SUM(ticketTotalWin) 
FROM tickets 
WHERE ticketDate > dateadd(hh,-1,getdate()) AND ticketDate < GETDATE()
     AND ticketState = 'WIN'
```

I have to subtract the values from the results of the queries:
first - second, and then insert it into the single column of another table and the way I insert values into another table is as so:

```
insert into ticketsAmounts (totalAmountPlay, totalAmountStandBy, totalAmountLose, totalAmountRefused, totalAmountWin, totalAmountClosed, totalAmountPayout, totalAmountRating, totalTickets)
SELECT
    (select SUM(ticketTotalAmount) 
     from tickets
    where ticketDate > dateadd(hh,-1,getdate()) 
         AND ticketDate < GETDATE()
         AND ticketState IN ('STAND BY' , 'WIN' , 'LOSE')),
    (select SUM(ticketTotalAmount) 
       from tickets 
       where ticketDate > dateadd(hh,-1,getdate()) 
       AND ticketDate < GETDATE() AND ticketState = 'STAND BY'),
    (select SUM(ticketTotalAmount) 
      from tickets
      where ticketDate > dateadd(hh,-1,getdate()) 
      AND ticketDate < GETDATE() AND ticketState = 'LOSE'),
```

This is just the part but You get the point, and both of those summed values are also inserted into columns of table2, I have tried placing selects into select but it isn't working and it looks appalling!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can now easily calculate the diff between two SUM result.

```
SELECT 
SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN ticketState IN ('STAND BY' , 'WIN' , 'LOSE') THEN ticketTotalAmount 
            ELSE 0 
        END
) AS TotalAmount,
SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN ticketState = 'WIN' THEN ticketTotalWin 
            ELSE 0 
        END
) AS TotalWin
FROM tickets
WHERE ticketDate > DATEADD(hh,-1,GETDATE()) AND ticketDate < GETDATE()
```

For getting differences between two sum, just use this following query which will return a single value. You can use this for insert purpose as well.

```
SELECT 
SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN ticketState IN ('STAND BY' , 'WIN' , 'LOSE') THEN ticketTotalAmount 
            ELSE 0 
        END
) -
SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN ticketState = 'WIN' THEN ticketTotalWin 
            ELSE 0 
        END
) AS TotalDifference
FROM tickets
WHERE ticketDate > DATEADD(hh,-1,GETDATE()) AND ticketDate < GETDATE()
```

Comment: this would work as an individual query but this query has to retrieve a single value, which will be placed in the corresponding column of the second table via insert into select statement

Comment: Query with calculated difference is added.

Answer (score 2):

You want conditional aggregation for the difference:

```
SELECT (SUM(ticketTotalAmount) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN ticketState = 'WIN' THEN ticketTotalWin ELSE 0 END)
       ) as diff
FROM tickets
WHERE ticketDate > dateadd(hour, 1, getdate()) AND
      ticketDate < GETDATE() AND
      ticketState IN ('STAND BY', 'WIN' , 'LOSE');
```

I don't see how the other columns are calculated for the `insert`, but I suspect the same method can be used.

Comment: the result I get here is null even though the ticketTotalAmount when run individually  has value, could it be the way that sql works, if it subtracts a null value field from the existing value e.g. 1241254 - null the result will be null?

Comment: @MicroDev92 . . . The `ELSE` should prevent that, unless the `WHERE` filters would *all* rows.